# Text file outputted via FileOutputStream

Tags: android, textview, fileoutputstream

How would you output a Text File just so I could see the individual lines of text in the LogCat. The file is in the res/raw/ directory and I just need very basic help on how to do this. I already have the code required to get the information provided by the FileOutputStream but am unsure how to get it to read it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a text file from the raw resource folder you can use the following snippet:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(YOUR_RESOURCE_ID)));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // Do whatever with the read line here
    // to write it to logcat e.g. use Log.i("TAG", line);
}
br.close();
```

Comment: I get several errors with that. Firstly: Cannot resolve method getresources and second br.readLine = unhandled exception IO Exception

Comment: getResources() can only be used from a Context (e.g. from within an Activity). If you don't have one you'll have to pass one through. The unhandled IOException is because the whole thing needs to be wrapped by a try/catch. I ommited that part for simplicity